# FirebaseError: Expected type 'Zu', but it was: a custom uh object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to update a maped data inside of another mapped object. It shows this message

[image]

Comment: Welcome on StackOveflow ! [Why don't show image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3585796) ?

Answer (score 0):

The [`updateDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#updatedoc) function takes a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) as first parameter and not a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot). Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
// Pass reference of that document, cityRef in this case
// You can also access the doc ref by `artichoke.ref` as well

updateDoc(cityRef, {
  maxCart: {
    tomato: {
      cart: false
    }
  }
})
```