# How do I copy collection documents in firebase cloud store?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection for user's cart items. I'm trying to copy them to orders collection once the user successfully checks-out so that I can delete the cart collection. However, I keep getting an error message saying "[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiBQd.png)". Below is my code to query "orders" collection using product id (which is configured to be the document ID for each cart doc and is working as intended).

```
const getOrders = async (productData) => {

    const cartCollection = await collection(db, "users", currentUser.id, "cart");
    const cartQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(cartCollection);

    const orderCollection = await collection(db, "users", currentUser.id, "orders")
    const orderQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(orderCollection)
    const orderRef = doc(db, "users", currentUser.id, "orders", productData.id);
    
    const orderDoc = await getDoc(orderRef);
    if (!orderDoc.exists()) {
      await setDoc(orderRef, { quantity: 1 } );
    } else {
      // increment the product's quantity by 1
      let quantity = orderDoc.data().quantity;
      quantity++;
      // If the document already exists, increment value based on quantity and merge
      await updateDoc(
        orderRef,
        { quantity: Number(quantity) },
        { merge: true }
      );
    }
```

I'm able to query the cart documents and console log their id and quantity using the following:

```
cartQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, doc.data().quantity);
    });
```

Is there a way I can assign id and quantity of cart docs to order docs in the code block above. I apologize if my question is not clear, this is my first time posting and any feedback is appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy contents of my cart collection to orders collection using the following as reference: [FirebaseError: Expected type 'Zu', but it was: a custom uh object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71546322/firebaseerror-expected-type-zu-but-it-was-a-custom-uh-object)

```
const copyCart = useCallback(
    async (product) => {
      const orderCollectionRef = doc(
        db,
        "users",
        currentUser.id,
        "orders",
        product.id
      );
      const orderRef = await getDoc(orderCollectionRef);
      if (!orderRef.exists()) {
        await setDoc(orderCollectionRef, { quantity: 1 });
      } else {
        // increment the product's quantity by 1
        let quantity = product.quantity;
        // add update cart functionality
        await updateDoc(
          orderCollectionRef,
          { quantity: Number(quantity) },
          { merge: true }
        );
      }
      getOrders();
    },
    [db, currentUser.id]);
```

I was referencing the document incorrectly and once I passed in the correct reference, it worked. See code below:

```
const orderRef = await getDoc(orderCollectionRef);
          if (!orderRef.exists()) {
            await setDoc(orderCollectionRef, { quantity: 1 });
```

I was able to loop over individual cart items and pass their document reference by calling the code below:

```
for (let item of cartItems.items) {copyCart(item)}
```